# Python Flask/JSON: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to write a webserver with Flask and e.g. have following function for post:

```
@app.route('/v1/tasks', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    data=request.get_json()
    title=data["title"]
    tasks.append(json.dumps({"id": len(tasks), "title": title, "is_completed": "false"}))
    index=len(tasks)-1
    return json.dumps({"id":index}), 200
```

title=data["title"] throws following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The input format for POST should be:

```
{title: "Test Task 2"}
```

I am confused because I saw a different post function, where access the contents of the JSON worked like this:

```
@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    data=request.get_json()
    dictionary[data["key"]]=data["value"]
    data["message"]="success"
    return json.dumps(data)
```

What do I need to change so that I can access the title from the input JSON?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong. Verify if you are using the correct MIME media type for posting JSON, which is application/json. Test your Flask server with this code and see if it works correctly.

```
import requests

response = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/v1/tasks', json={'title': "Test Task 2"})
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: A side note, when just running flask, I saw * Serving Flask app "project1-backend.py"                                       t.
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ Is there anything I need to keep in mind for this warning?

Comment: If you are just using this server internally, for deployment or testing, you can ignore this warning. But if you pretend to run your server in production, you must take some more steps. Follow this tutorial https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/deploy/